# TemplateDoesNotExist error when extending an app template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am having trouble setting up a template (under app directory) to extend a base.html that is in the root/templates/jinja2 directory

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/jinja2')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
         ...
        },
    }
]
```

folder structure:

```
apps
|---app1
    |---templates
        |---jinja2
            |---listing.html
|---templates
    |---jinja2
        |---base.html
```

listing.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
...
```

The error I am getting when I pull listing.html:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at ...
base.html

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /webapps/pickup/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /webapps/pickup/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /webapps/pickup/src/apps/listing/templates/base.html (Source does not exist)
```

What is the right way to extend to a base template in the root template folder?  I am using Django 3.0.5

Comment: Just want to note that If I put listing.html in root/templates/jinja2, there is no error.

Comment: Figured out the problem:  `listing.html` should be in `app1/jinja2/` not in `app1/templates/jinja2/`

Answer (score 0):

Make your folder structure proper

```
apps

|---app1

    |---templates

        |---app1

            |---listing.html
            |---base.html
```

Comment: I would like to put `base.html` in a `project_root/templates/base.html` so that it can be shared by all the apps.

Comment: just copy base.html and put it again in other apps template

Answer (score 0):

[**APP_DIRS**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines) means U can use ***templates*** folder in app what U've registered in settings.

To specify custom path U need to add **[NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines)** parameter.
Or just try to move *listing.html* in ***app1/templates/app1/***

Comment: If I switch to using django template, then `app1/templates/listing.html` and `project_root/templates/base.html` works.  But for some reasons, when I use jinja2, it doesn't find `base.html`